# Cancel CSS hover behavior with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, hover

The website I work on has a navigation menu (a CSS-formatted unordered list) with sub-menus for some of the categories (children unordered lists).

This CSS rule hides a submenu unordered list:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

And this CSS rule makes submenu unordered list appear when a visitor hovers the cursor over the top level menu link:

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {;
    display:block;
}
```

This is done for those (possibly non-existent) users who have JavaScript disabled in their browsers.

Now I'm spicing up that navigation menu with jQuery, and the very first thing that I need to do is disable the on hover behavior, dictated by CSS. For some reason I'm having hard time doing so, and could use some help. Here's what I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul').css('display', 'none');

});
```

No luck, CSS still controls the behavior, and the submenu pops up on hover, as if there's no jQuery present. Which means, I'm not doing it correctly.

I'd appreciate it if someone explained to me how this should be done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RLW3B/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.main-navigation ul li').on('mouseover',function(){
        $('.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul').css('display', 'none');
     });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, @roasted! Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Everything is perfect about this snippet, @roasted, with one exception. The script does not consider what happens if the user moves the mouse away from the link. Could you help a little further with it, please? I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I don't understang your issue, could you provide a sample or elaborate how to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I see you have some errors in console. First fix these errors by migrate your code using jquery migrate or upgrade plugins or downgrade jquery version. That's said, your menu behaviour is strange, i don't have time to debug all your site, im afraid. You should post your problem by opening a new question including all the code you use to set menu and submenu. Basically, the behaviour you seem to want for you menu as plenty of examples on the internet, you should be able to find one that fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is remove the `main-navigation` class from the parent. Otherwise, you cannot manipulate the styles of pseudo classes from JavaScript.

Comment: You mean, something like this, @techfoobar: $('.main-navigation ul').removeClass('.main-navigation'); - am I right?

Comment: removing class, you will loose all attached css style rules even some you would like to keep

Comment: Yeah, and for some mysterious reason, removing that class did not cancel the hover behavior, @roasted. (I suspect that I did it wrong, somehow.) Still – your solution is the best.

Comment: As roasted said, removing the class will also remove other styles as well, probably not what you want.